# What JS framework would you choose for mobile developement: JQuery Mobile or DOJO Mobile?

Tags: jquery, mobile, dojo, cordova

I'm a front end developer and I am interested in improving my skills fast and without spending years with Java or Obj C. I guess there are many like me.
I found a few JavaScript frameworks/toolkits:

1. DOJO with the Dojo Builder to choose the libraries you want to include in your prj.
   http://dojotoolkit.org/. DOJO is also cross platform and you don't need a MAC to build for iPhone.
2. jQuery Mobile: http://jquerymobile.com
   wich seems to be different than jQuery UI.
3. PhoneGap,based on HTML5 and JavaScript. The major drawback I found is you need a MAC to develop for iOS.

I want to mention I am more familiarized with jQuery but I found DOJO syntax quite familiar.

Any of you have some experience with any or the 3 of those? I would like to read pro vs cons about these.

Regards
Ovi

Comment: You should rephrase the question so that there could be one specific answer to it. Now it just invites to discussion, which should be done somewhere else than Stackoverflow.

Comment: I haven't found a similar question yet on stack overflow. jQuery Mobile vs Dojo Mobile

Comment: @Goran Gingic: That's because this type of question is usually closed.

Answer (score 2):

My personal suggestion:

1) Develop with Dojo Toolkit - use dojox.mobile, avoid dijits, for light-weight and native-looking widgets

2) Compile with Closure Compiler in Advanced Mode -- for runtime speed optimizations, tight packing and obfuscation (something you may need for a mobile app).  There is a how-to doc: http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/file/n2636749/Using_the_Dojo_Toolkit_with_the_Closure_Compiler.pdf

3) Use PhoneGap to package it as a native app (dojox.mobile is compatible with PhoneGap)